# font face not working on android chrome and firefox

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, mobile

I am having issues with the font face in CSS3. I am calling my font with the following code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: James Fajardo;  
src: url('https://www.twoseven.nl/kurkorganicwines/wp-
content/themes/kurk/fonts/James_Fajardo.ttf');  
}
```

The code works when using font-family: James Fajardo in my CSS on the preferred H2's or alinea's. It is also working in Chrome on my desktop. But, it is not working in Firefox or Chrome on Android mobile. Strangely enough it is working in Safari on iPhone.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I allready tried installing different font styles (like woff and woff2) but it is still not working on the Android device.

Thnx in advance!
Rob

Comment: i think you need more formats (.svg, .woff, .woff2, .. ) more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.paulirish.com/2010/font-face-gotchas/#smiley

Answer (score 0):

Try using local path to your font. Sometimes it works.

```
@font-face{font-family:James Fajardo;src:url(James_Fajardo.ttf)}
```